# .htaccess rewriterule to change image on a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foobar
RewriteRule /foobar /barfoo [R=301,L]
```

With this rule, going to

> https://www.somewhere.com/foobar

will redirect to

> https://www.somewhere.com/barfoo

Easy and simple. Now, I'm trying the same technique to change an image on a specific page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} about
RewriteRule /wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo.png /wp-content/uploads/logo/logo.png [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working. Both /wp-content links are working. I have another rule which is working fine tough with the geoip module:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_REGION} !^(COUNTRY)$
RewriteRule logo.png https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wp-content/uploads/logo/logo-new.png [L]
```

Which means, if the user is not in COUNTRY, then give him a different logo image.

**UPDATE:**
This works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/logo.png$ https://website.com/new-logo.png [L]
```

But this doesn't:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} about
RewriteRule ^.*/logo.png$ https://website.com/new-logo.png [L]
```

The RewriteCond works. The RewriteRule works. But not when they are being used together.

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**

Would have been great to do it in htaccess but cannot find the solution. Instead I went another way by modifying the template in PHP.

```
if ( ($_SERVER['GEOIP_REGION'] <> 'COUNTRY') && (!stristr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'], 'about')) )  
  echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/logo/new-logo.png">';
else  
  echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/logo/logo.png">';
```

Comment: remove this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} about`

Comment: I can't remove it since I want to change the logo.png on just one specific page.

Comment: what you have to check is `%{HTTP_REFERER}`, it does not make sense to check `%{REQUEST_URI}` and you rewrite the pattern `/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo.png`

Comment: Can you write the whole thing? I've tried many different combinations but still nothing is working.

Comment: just read on HTTP_REFERER, that is not what I need since it the URL of the last visited website. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 0):

You should make clear that, for the below `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} about
RewriteRule /wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo.png /wp-content/uploads/logo/logo.png [R=301,L]
```

If users are requesting the page `http://example.com/about`, the `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/about`, which matches the `RewriteCond`. But the `RewriteRule` pattern, `/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo.png` does not match `/about`.

The `logo` is another request, `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo.png`. The `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo.png`, that does not match the `RewriteCond`.

That's the reason why the `RewriteRule` does not work in this case.

If you want to change the logo only in about page, there is one simple trick to do that. When the logo is first loaded on the about page, browser will add the `referer` header to the request headers. The `referer` header can be `http://example.com/about`, or the css file, depending on which last resource requesting the `logo`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} about
RewriteRule /wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo.png /wp-content/uploads/logo/logo.png [L]
```

Make sure that you clear the browser cache. The flag `R=301` is permanent redirect which is cached by the browser.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. It just doesn't work. I cleared my cache but I still always receive the original logo.png, never the new one. Doesn't even work to change the logo when I use: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} * or (.*) or "" or just leaving it empty. The condition is never met, don't know why.

Comment: you should start with devtools network panel (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/). It helps you to check which request headers made by the logo.png. It is not guarantee that the logo.png `referer` header is about page.